# Length of App ID, Registration ID, Device ID of C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I was wondering the length of App ID and Registration ID, and Device ID of Android OS when used on using C2DM.

If anyone who've used C2DM system, could you share the length of those 3 aspects?

Thank you

Comment: I have developed C2DM some times back. As far as I can remember, no one tells exact answer for your question. I have used 1024 size and varchar as data type to store those IDs in my database, specially RegistrationID. It works for me. For further reading... http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

Comment: I wonder why C2DM has so few of Official Documents... so many uncertainties!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. App ID means your application manifest package name.
2. Device id seams like this 5245rc9e56g648f6 (this is example device id.)
3. Registration Id is string having numeric data also. It should have more than 100 characters.(this will be generated by google c2dm server)

If You wanna see those, then just make a sample app and use Logs for those.

You can get more info from [here](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)

Comment: For App Id Thank you. It really helped! Registration ID... not still sure yet.. I don't think it is actually fixed length. I've seen other questions and saw MAXIMUM length is 4K. might have to put length before it lol

Comment: yes, Registration Id is not fixed length. you can get some info from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/141a5be624fc8c3)